# How can I color 4 different headings in a black-and-white PDF simultaneously?

Tags: pdf

1. [Click to download the PDF](https://www.mediafire.com/file/w4qbhvkz69xa3ss/Simester_and_Sullivan%27s_Criminal_Law_%282016_6_ed%29_-_D%2C_Content_Removed.pdf/file). Ought the little-known publisher have lessened the file size from 253 MB?
2. Anyway, how can I color only the 4 different headings most methodically and quickly? Coloring each  is obviously too unproductive.
3. The snag is that some of the book's content (that oughtn't be colored) may match heading 4's font formatting. See the combined screenshot beneath.

[image]

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? Just my opinion, but questions should *not* require *any* download of a file, even a PDF.

Comment: have you tried selecting the text and clicking the black box on the right?

Comment: @Junme You're not suggesting coloring each, separately, right?

Comment: If the PDF is structured, you could use the structure tree as a guide. This does, however, not protect you from wrongfully use of the structure type. Otherwise, if a visual check of the context is needed, you will be best off by doing it manually.

Comment: @scott One of the things with PDF is that there is no particular way to give advice only from screenshot especially in cases when programming/scripting is needed. As you see  now there is only unlucky guessing takes place.

Comment: @scott I'm on it. Just didn't had time to check PDF yet as it's not possible to make analysis via phone. There is a solution, but I'm not sure if it's possible in Acrobat without quite expensive plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it will not be possible without scripting. There is no built-in tools in Acrobat that can select particular text by font name, size and style.

Comment: Thanks again! How can I do this with 'scripting'? Is it challenging?

Comment: 2. Can I select particular text by "font name, size"?  I removed the third criterion of  'style', which means bold or italics.

Comment: Start with this one: https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/javascript_console